# How to join two tables from a table with a property as list

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have two tables and their respective POCO classes as:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> CarIds { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set;}
}
```

and I have a DTOs as

```
public class PersonDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

A Person may have have **no or many** cars.

How can I write a LinQ query to create `PersonDTO` from `List<Person>`(Persons) and `List<Car>` (Cars)?

I have started as

```
var q = (from p in Persons
         from c in Cars.Where(x => p.CarIds.Contains(x.Id))
         select new PersonDTO
         {
             Id = p.Id,
             Name = p.Name,
             Cars = c
         }).ToList();
```

But I get the following error :

> An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses
>   optional arguments.

How should I write this query?

I think providing further information on this issue is quite necessary because I might be misleading fellow members.

Actually I am using MongoDB as datasource and my actual code is as follows :

```
IMongoCollection<Person> persons = db.GetCollection<Person>("person");
IMongoCollection<Car> cars = db.GetCollection<Car>("car");

var model = (from p in persons.AsQueryable<Person>()
             from c in cars.AsQueryable<Car>().Where(x => p.CarIds.Contains(x.Id))
             select new PersonDTO
             {
                 Id = p.Id,
                 Name = p.Name,
                 Cars = c
             }).ToList();
```

I also tried

```
var model = (from p in persons.AsQueryable<Person>()
             select new PersonDTO
             {
                 Id = p.Id,
                 Name = p.Name,
                 Cars = cars.AsQueryable<Person>().Where(x => b.CarIds.Contains(x.Id))
             }).ToList();
```

But I still get the same error.

And about the relations since I am not using a RDBMS car dos not exclusively belong to one person as it is in daily life. Car is something like a tag. I think it would be better to think it like the tags in the StackOverfow. Each tag is unique, each posy has zero , one or many tags and many posts might have the same tag in your post. When I display my post I get the tags I have entered. What I want is such a relationship.

I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: you missed a bracket after `from c in Cars.Where(x => p.CarIds.Contains(x.Id)` but I don't know if that resolves the issue or it's just a copy&paste error

Comment: @PhilippSchmid Thank you for the warning. That was just a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

updated
I have tried this in Linqpad and it's work.

```
void Main()
{
    var Persons = new List<Person>() { new Person { CarIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 } }, new Person { CarIds = new List<int> { 4, 5 } } };
    var Cars = new List<Car>() { new Car { Id = 1 }, new Car { Id = 2 }, new Car { Id = 3 }, new Car { Id = 4 }, new Car { Id = 5 } };

    (from p in Persons
     select new PersonDTO
     {
         Id = p.Id,
         Name = p.Name,
         Cars = Cars.Where(x => p.CarIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList()
     }).ToList().Dump();
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> CarIds { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
public class PersonDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

What is your data source from? database?

Comment: Unfortunately when I try this I still get the "An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments" error.